# Create chart in AngularJS with CSS styles

Tags: css, angularjs, html

I'm trying to create a chart in my web app using angularJS. Creating the table was easy, but defining color styles in a CSS and get the chart function to get the style seams impossible. The biggest problem I have found is that I have to define the bar color in a variable. The only way to do it using a CSS file is get the string from the file itself when I create the data to build the table.

my html code:

```
 <canvas class="col-md-12" tc-chartjs-bar chart-data="Data" chart-options="options" style="pointer-events: none"></canvas>
```

my JS

```
 $scope.Data = {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [
              {
                  fillColor: 'rgba(250,233,239,1)',
                  description: 'Pendentes de Envio',
                  data: [123]
              },
              {
                  fillColor: 'rgba(236,164,191,1)',
                  data: [280]
              },
            {
                fillColor: 'rgba(226,96,155,1)',
                data: [128]
            },
            {
                fillColor: 'rgba(193,120,150,1)',
                data: [150]
            },
            {
                fillColor: 'rgba(229,202,216,1)',
                data: [321]
            }
            ],
            onClick: null
        };
```

I'm using tc-chart, but it seams to be equal to all of them.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your question. It's hard to tell what you want. Are you asking how to change the colors in the bar chart using the CSS without parsing through the CSS itself?

Comment: Yes,  chart.js request that the color is sent as a parameter,  and I want to define it in a style,  so I can use it in different pages. I have researched about it and the only way I've found is to parse the css document and find the string that has the color.  What I am trying to do,  it's applying a style to the bar I want to draw so I can override css styles without need to change my code.

Comment: Are you using td-chart or chart.js? And if you can make a plunker, that will be easy for people to help you.

Comment: This one is made by achudars, but it's the same, i have to use variables and can not use styles
http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/NXPhL/